# Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation from the GCP API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, service-accounts

Our team is converting the manual process for creating a GCP project, creating a service account and enabling G Suite Domain-wide delegation on the service account to an automated process via Python.

We're able to create the service account following this documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/create

However, there seems to be little to no documentation on how to enable this on a service account using the API. All the documentation we find is telling us to enable the setting from the GCP console which does not help for our automation.
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Comment: Great question.  This is a glaring omission in GCP. Very frustrating

Answer (score 1):

You must enable G Suite Domain Wide Delegation in the console. This is not possible via the CLI or other tools.

Comment: If this is true that's huge bummer. Is there no way to create an OAuth2 Client and link it the service account?

Comment: @njgrisafi - I am not sure what you asked about the OAuth2 Client. All Google IAM is via OAuth. Domain Wide Delegation is via a service account. Please reread my answer. You must follow the instructions and use the console. There is no other way. Once you have a service account with Domain Wide Delegation you can use that with your tool chains.

Comment: Please try the following two links that might help you create the automation scripts using Python for your [service account creation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) and  [delegating a domain wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount?&_ga=2.13149239.1847114482.1580158620-496180248.1577744947#delegatingauthority).

Comment: @MdDaudWalizarif - How are those links related to my answer? Enabling Domain wide delegation must be performed in the console and cannot be enabled by a python program. Once enabled, the service account can be used in any lanuage.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am not challenging the comments of John Hanley. There was a simple misunderstanding. In fact, I up voted his comments.

Comment: Possible to configure OAuth using Alpha iap API - https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/programmatic-oauth-clients